# 3-speed DC fan control with Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

I have built this MOSFET circuit, which is supposed to run 2 DC fans using an Arduino Uno.

[image]

I am trying to get the two DC fans running with four settings: OFF, LOW, MED and HIGH. I have been having issues with the MED option, because when its option is selected by the rotary switch (5 V pulse detected by the analog pin A2) the speed of the fan is not the constant 75% duty cycle (191) as defined on line 75 in the code below:

```js
int motorPin1 = 3;
int motorPin2 = 9;
int DCfanSpeed = 0;
int voltageZero = 0;
int voltageOne = 1;
int voltageTwo = 2;
int voltageThree = 3;    

void setup() {
  pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(voltageZero, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(voltageOne, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(voltageTwo, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(voltageThree, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int voltageReadingZero = analogRead(voltageZero); // OFF SWITCH
  int voltsZero = voltageReadingZero / 204.6;
  if (voltsZero == 5) {
    delay(300);
    if (voltsZero == 5) DCfanSpeed = 0;
    // else DCfanSpeed = DCfanSpeed;
    while (voltsZero == 5) {
      analogWrite(motorPin1, DCfanSpeed);
      analogWrite(motorPin2, DCfanSpeed);
      voltageReadingZero = analogRead(voltageZero);
      voltsZero = voltageReadingZero / 204.6;
    }
  }
  int voltageReadingOne = analogRead(voltageOne); // LOW SWITCH
  int voltsOne = voltageReadingOne / 204.6;
  if (voltsOne == 5) {
    delay(300);
    if (voltsOne == 5) DCfanSpeed = 128;
    //else DCfanSpeed = DCfanSpeed;
    while (voltsOne == 5) {
      analogWrite(motorPin1, DCfanSpeed);
      analogWrite(motorPin2, DCfanSpeed);
      voltageReadingOne = analogRead(voltageOne);
      voltsOne = voltageReadingOne / 204.6;
    }
  }
  int voltageReadingTwo = analogRead(voltageTwo); //  MED SWITCH
  int voltsTwo = voltageReadingTwo / 204.6;
  if (voltsTwo == 5) {
    delay(300);
    if (voltsTwo == 5) DCfanSpeed = 191;
    //else DCfanSpeed = DCfanSpeed;
    while (voltsTwo == 5) {
      analogWrite(motorPin1, DCfanSpeed);
      analogWrite(motorPin2, DCfanSpeed);
      voltageReadingTwo = analogRead(voltageTwo);
      voltsTwo = voltageReadingTwo / 204.6;
    }
  }
  int voltageReadingThree = analogRead(voltageThree);  //  HIGH SWITCH
  int voltsThree = voltageReadingThree / 204.6;
  if (voltsThree == 5) {
    delay(300);
    if (voltsThree == 5) DCfanSpeed = 255;
    //else DCfanSpeed = DCfanSpeed;
    while (voltsThree == 5) {
      analogWrite(motorPin1, DCfanSpeed);
      analogWrite(motorPin2, DCfanSpeed);
      voltageReadingThree = analogRead(voltageThree);
      voltsThree = voltageReadingThree / 204.6;
    }
  }
}
```

Excuse the poor formatting but the basic rundown of the medium option is such that the voltage across the analog pin 2 is measured and converted into volts and if it is 5 Volts (rotary turned to the medium position) then it enters a while loop where the voltage is monitored such that if there is any change then there must be a speed setting change. This is the only option for which I get this pulsating speed on the fans instead of smooth and continuos operation.

Any ideas about how I could improve this? I have taken away one fan to see if one was faulty but this didn't work.

Comment: *"Excuse the poor formatting"*. I have done it for you but in the future please do a **Tools > Auto Format** on your code before posting.

Comment: Why are you using `analogRead()` to read a digital signal from a switch...?

Comment: Because if I use digital read won't the compiler assume that I am talking about one of the digital pins on the UNO board and not the analog pins? I have to use the analog pins to detect the 5V signal because the digital pins are way too receptive to interference and switch on and off arbitrarily especially when there is the ports of a rotary switch connected there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved simply by condensing code and getting rid of unnecessary variable declarations.

Corrected program:

```
    int motorPin1 = 3;
    int motorPin2 = 9;
    int DCfanSpeed = 0; 




    void setup() 
    { 
      pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(motorPin2, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(A0, INPUT_PULLUP);
      digitalWrite(A1, INPUT_PULLUP);
      digitalWrite(A2, INPUT_PULLUP);
      digitalWrite(A3, INPUT_PULLUP);
      Serial.begin(9600);
    } 


    void loop() 
     { 


       int voltsZero = analogRead(A0)/204.6; // OFF SWITCH
       if(voltsZero == 5)
        {
          delay(300);
          if(voltsZero == 5) DCfanSpeed = 0;

           while(voltsZero == 5) 
            {
              analogWrite(motorPin1, DCfanSpeed);
              analogWrite(motorPin2, DCfanSpeed);
              voltsZero = analogRead(A0)/204.6;

            }
         }

      int voltsOne = analogRead(A1)/204.6;    // LOW SWITCH
      if(voltsOne == 5)
        {
          delay(300);
          if(voltsOne == 5) DCfanSpeed = 128;
          while(voltsOne == 5)
           {
             analogWrite(motorPin1, DCfanSpeed);
             analogWrite(motorPin2, DCfanSpeed); 
             voltsOne = analogRead(A1)/204.6;
           }
        }

       int voltsTwo = analogRead(A2)/204.6;  //  MED SWITCH
       if(voltsTwo == 5)
        {
          delay(300);
          if(voltsTwo == 5) DCfanSpeed = 191;
          while(voltsTwo == 5)
           {
             analogWrite(motorPin1, DCfanSpeed);
             analogWrite(motorPin2, DCfanSpeed);
             voltsTwo = analogRead(A2)/204.6;

           }
        }

      int voltsThree = analogRead(A3)/204.6;  //  HIGH SWITCH
      if(voltsThree == 5)
        {
          delay(300);
          if(voltsThree == 5) DCfanSpeed = 255;
          while(voltsThree == 5) 
           {
             analogWrite(motorPin1, DCfanSpeed);
             analogWrite(motorPin2, DCfanSpeed);
             voltsThree = analogRead(A3)/204.6;
           }
         }

    }
```

Comment: Accept you own answer to close this question.